# Embedding a SWF Video in an AIR 2 HTML App

Tags: flash, air, embed

I've been through the forums for awhile and I can verify that my issue doesn't have to do with transparency or chrome.  I have an IFRAME which is in the *application sandbox*, giving it access to files in **app-storage**.  Dynamic images are loading fine, but my dynamically generated `<OBJECT>` code that is placed in the DOM is not loading the SWF video.  I can see the object placeholder, but no video.

Are there any requirements to embedding a SWF file, perhaps size requirements (both height and width required)?  Given the fact that my content is dynamic and I don't know the dimensions of the SWF file, I currently have two options for embedding:

1. Calculate the height and width of
   the parent element, and assign those
   values to the OBJECT params.
2. Use 100% width and height on the OBJECT

This might pose problems with the proportions of the SWF file, which I'm hoping can be fixed by the scale `PARAM` ( http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html ).

Please help, I haven't been able to find any helpful guides yet.  I have already followed the documentation for embedding from here to no avail:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS4B441C24-BAE3-4110-91FD-A4E5EEFB2467.html

Comment: its hard to say w/o seeing your code, but you always have an option to load your swf directly from AIR and display it to end-user, its a pity but not inside of iframe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the hell of it, here is an extensive SWFObject I generated which is working (although overkill):

```
var SWFObject = document.createElement("object");
SWFObject.setAttribute("type", "application/x-shockwave-flash");
SWFObject.setAttribute("classid", "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000");
SWFObject.setAttribute("width", "100%");
SWFObject.setAttribute("height", "100%");
SWFObject.setAttribute("id", "movie");

var param1 = document.createElement("param");
param1.setAttribute("name", "movie");
param1.setAttribute("value", 'app-storage:' + filename);

var param2 = document.createElement("param");
param2.setAttribute("wmode", "opaque");

var param3 = document.createElement("param");
param3.setAttribute("bgcolor", "#FFFFFF");

var param4 = document.createElement("param");
param4.setAttribute("allowscriptaccess", "always");

var param5 = document.createElement("param");
param5.setAttribute("quality", "high");

var param6 = document.createElement("param");
param6.setAttribute("flashvars", "wmode=opaque");

var param7 = document.createElement("param");
param7.setAttribute("scale", "ShowAll");

var param8 = document.createElement("param");
param8.setAttribute("classid", "clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000");

SWFObject.appendChild(param1);
SWFObject.appendChild(param2);
SWFObject.appendChild(param3);
SWFObject.appendChild(param4);
SWFObject.appendChild(param5);
SWFObject.appendChild(param6);
SWFObject.appendChild(param7);
SWFObject.appendChild(param8);
```